# LLVM IR bitcode file versioning

Tags: llvm, versioning, llvm-ir

I have LLVM IR files in textual form that were compiled targeting different LLVM versions. In my LLVM IR interpreter I want to identify which parser I should select to parse such a file, since the textual format is [not backward compatible](http://llvm.org/docs/DeveloperPolicy.html#ir-backwards-compatibility). However, I cannot see a version ID in these files.

If I instead change my parsers to parse the bit code files, I have longer compatibility guarantees. There is also a [version field](http://llvm.org/docs/BitCodeFormat.html#bitcode-wrapper-format) but the documentation mentions that it is currently always 0.

So is there any way to identify the LLVM version of a bit code file, or do I have no other choice than letting the user specify the version?

Comment: That's a question better asked on the [LLVM developer mailing list](http://lists.llvm.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/llvm-dev), I guess.

Comment: Thanks! I followed your advice and asked on the LLVM mailing list.